# How to exclude reused pooled logins from log collection

Tags: sql-server, authentication, connection-pooling, audit-logging

I've created a standard audit in SSMS by navigating to Security->Audits->Right click->New Audit and tying it to Security->Server Audit Specification->Right click->New Server Audit Specification which includes capturing the three Groups:
SUCCESSFUL_DATABASE_AUTHENTICATION_GROUP
FAILED_LOGIN_GROUP
SUCCESSFUL_LOGIN_GROUP

The problem I'm having is my logs are filling up at an accelerated rate due to an application using the reused pooled connections, causing collections of upwards of 10GBs a day per server.

Is there a way to exclude logins that are reused from a pooled connection when they occur rather than recording them? If possible, I'd still like the initial connection to be recorded.

Answer (score 0):

In the audit logs, there is a field named "additional_information" that contains text within it that reads <pooled_connection>(0 or 1)</pooled_connection>.

Now, I didn't find any great documentation on what this value signifies, but after some in house testing we found:
0 = initial pooled connection or non pooled connection
1 = Reused pooled connection

In order to keep reused connections out of my log, I used the filter within the Audit itself, and added:
([Additional_Information] like '%<pooled_connection>0</pooled_connection>%')

This seems to work!